# Xsltproc and Office web archive

Tags: html, xml, xslt, ms-word

I'm stuck with a problem with `xsltproc`.

I have a file saved with `Word 2010` as `"Web page in a single file"` ([Click me for source](http://www.dbtecno.it/upload/test.mht))
in which there's only a string **"TEST TEST"**.

I would like to substitute the string with something taken from and XML so i thought `xsltproc` was good.

Since the `mht` file is not a proper xml-formatted file i'm already stuck.

My question about `xsltproc` are:

- How can i make xsltproc accept xml entities like `<meta name=3DGenerator content=3D"Microsoft Word 14">`? The `3D` outside quotes make it angry.
- Can I skip parts with no xml formatting? Like the very first lines:

---

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_NextPart_01CDFED3.EFE26A80"
..
```

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: Word is using XML as its way of saving files nowadays, try one of those formats instead - I think one of the is a flat XML file that you can use in the way you want. XSLT will never be able to manage the HTTP multipart file you supplied.

Comment: I know... but the strings i need to replace are in HTML format... So i need them to be into an html file

Comment: The `3D` there is part of the encoding used in saving the file's multiple components as a MIME format.  You would need some way to unencode the content. But even if you do that, the HTML in that file is not XML. The lack of quotes on `name=` is one indication of that, and the `>` instead of `/>` at the end of the `<meta>` tag is another. I think it would be rather tricky to use an XSLT with that as the input.